# How I do View C Drive?

Tags: 12.04, data-recovery, windows-vista

I Run 12.04 LTS on a HP Pavillion Notebook with 250GB GB HDD. I recently found an emutlaor and noticed something weird. I had a Z: Drive and C: Drive. The C: Drive is the same as it was in windows. My Vista Installation Went belly Up and got a BSOD at loading the OS. Is it possible to access these folders to see if I can recover anything?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you still have the Windows partition on your drive. To double check, Run `sudo fdisk -l` to list the partitions. It will give you an output similar to,

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00008ec7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        1013     8136891   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda2            1014        1044      249007+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5            1014        1044      248976   83  Linux
```

Notice the /dev/sdaX part. If you have Windows, it may show up as Extended or VFAT or NTFS depending on the file system.

To view the files in the partition, you need to mount it first. In your home directory, create a folder called `win` and then mount it by typing

```
$ mkdir win
$ mount /dev/sda2 win
```

If all goes well, then you will be able to do a `cd win` and then an `ls` to list all your files.

Comment: I do not have Windows any more. When I installed I got rid of it, but the partition is still there.

Comment: You should be able to access the contents of the partition using the method described above.

Comment: Thank you for your help, my uncle went through and found nothing from windows existing. It's Okay I made back ups before the BSOD, but using my netbook I have new stuff to put on this machine.